# Implementing up navigation with fragments without Support library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Suppose we have activity with dynamic fragments. There is some "root" fragment, and it is added like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new RootFragment())
            .addToBackStack("root")
            .commit();
    }
}
```

There are also some other fragments, which replaces this root fragment according to some logic. And we want to implement home button on `ActionBar`, which allows us to go from any fragment to the root. So, we call anywhere `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and override `onOptionsItemSelected` in our activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            fm.popBackStack("root", 0);
            return true;
        …
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This code works. But an issue appeared. When we press Back on root fragment, it just disappears from activity, we see empty screen and need to press Back once again to close application. I understand that it is correct behaviour according to the code I wrote and I need to remove `addToBackStack` to fix it. But in that case the home button implementation will not work.

The fix I see is overriding `onBackPressed` as following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
```

But it seems unnaturally. Fragments should make code cleaner, not like this.

So, how to do it correct? I think that it is typical task and probably it is a silly question. But in official documentation I've found only [one solution](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html), and it is about Support library, which I don't want to use.

Or my dirty hack is OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on the similar task in my project and in my opinion your "hack" is ok: since root `Activity` may itself have a layout, popping last fragment backstack state will lead to showing `Activity` in its initial state. I think this scenario is common and the fact that your root `Activity` has no layout is just a special case. My case, if you interested:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() <= (Const.isTablet ? 3 : 2)) {
        Utils.getStyledAlertDialogBuilder(this, R.string.confirm_finish)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_app)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.finish, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```